# The same certificate installed on different servers has different certification path. One works, one does not

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, x509, certificate

We had an interesting problem come up. We solved it be re-installing the cert that does not successfully encrypt a message. I'm wondering if anybody knows how the same cert can display a different chain.

On one server, the encryption was working and successfully communicating with our business partner. On this server, our cert was chained to: “VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA – G3” then “VeriSign”.

On the other server, the encryption failed. The cert was chained to “VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA – G3” but then goes to “VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority – G5” and then “VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary CA”.

I don't understand how they can be different.

Comment: Was the chain (from in-use to base) for the certs of length > 3? Since/IIRC the trust path is loaded on demand (ie: is not actually wholly declared within the encryption certificate you are using) ... I am wondering if the certs named "VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA – G3" were indeed different certs on the two machines?

Comment: It sounds like the failing machine could be missing `VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA – G3`. Install it in the certificate store and try again.

Answer (score 2):

2 possibilities come to mind:

1) Check to see if you're sending the same intermediate cert on both. Some cert vendors offer different intermediates that chain back to different roots, for compatibility reasons.

2) Check to see that both systems have the same CA keys installed (on RHEL/CentOS, this would be the "ca-certificates" package).